# Struggling to reference Property value at test case level in soap ui

Tags: soapui

I'm trying to extract the property value which exists in the test script level, but I'm always getting a null value. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

This is my code:

```
def username = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue( "RefId" )

log.info username
```

RefID has a value, which I've verified, I can't return the value from a test case level.

Comment: Your code works for me. Are you sure the property hasn't been defined at the test suite or project level? The properties are also case sensitive, so 'RefId` in your code won't match a 'RefID` property name.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
def username = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.testSuites["TestSuite 1"].testCases["TestCase 1"].getPropertyValue("RefId")

log.info username
```